# Can I see what my active bounties are while doing an expedition?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I picked up some bounties while in the town, and then started an expedition. I couldn't remember exactly what the bounties were I picked up. I opened both the map and the field guide, but didn't see them anywhere.

Is there anywhere in the UI while out on an expedition that I can see my active bounties, or do I need to go back to town / remember what they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure is! On PS4, the path is:

<kbd>Options</kbd>

```
-> Info

   -> Resource Center

      -> Bounties
```

(I assume XBox has something approximately equivalent)

Comment: Yep, it's in the same place on Xbox. Thanks for the help!